# Using jquery with java swing

Tags: java, jquery, swing

Is it possible to develop an application using `java swing` and `jquery` hand-in-hand? I want to make an application which is a kind of form . I am planning to develop GUI in swing . But, I m also looking forward to use jQuery in that.So is it possible?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: lol..nice reply ;) so that means its not possible.

Comment: It wouldn't even make sense

Comment: You can deploy your Java Swing application using [tag:java-web-start].